# Load an xhtml file to a div element using CORS and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cors

I want to load a page from another domain to a div element in my page. I'm using CORS and it works since it shows the file is loaded in console log but I cannot manage to add it to my div. 
Here's my code to make it more clear:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createCORSRequest(method, url){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
            xhr.open(method, url, true);
        } else if (typeof XDomainRequest !== "undefined"){
            xhr = new XDomainRequest();
            xhr.open(method, url);
        } else {
            xhr = null;
        }
        return xhr;
    }

    var request = createCORSRequest("get", "http://localhost:8080/test/header.xhtml");
    if (request){
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState === 4) {
                if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                    var hpage = request.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("theader").innerHTML = hpage;
                } else {
                    alert("An error occured! Request Status: +"request.status);
                }
            }
        };
        request.send();
    }            
</script>    
<body>
    <div id="theader"></div>
</body>
```

How do I display the loaded page in `theader` div?

**UPDATE** 
I found out that this happens in firefox and chrome because I use localhost. It works in ie but it only loads the text without css and images. Any idea how can I load the whole page into the div?
I guess my question now will be does the page load with all resources in CORS like it does with iframe? If so how?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in the console log? What does request.responseText contain? Can you put a break point there and check? a

Comment: Also you are not checking if the request returned 200 and its ready state = 4 (request finished and response is ready)

Comment: I updated my code to check for ready state check and I found out that request status is 0 and there's an error. But how do I find out what the error is?

Comment: I found out that this happens in firefox and chrome because I use localhost. It works in ie but it only loads the text without styling. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

A `div` element is meant to contain only certain HTML elements: in a nutshell the elements that you can find in the `body`. But not all HTML elements, and in particular not a `html` or `head` element. This is why your code does not work.

To solve your problem you either need to use an `iframe` (but from your question it seems this is not what you want), or put the content of the `body` element in the div and parse the head and load it in the current head.

Something like that (not tested):

```
var hpage = document.createElement("html");
hpage.innerHtml = request.responseText;

//Below you might want to write more robust code
//depending on the content of the response and how much you trust it
var head = hpage.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var body = hpage.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
document.getElementById("theader").innerHTML = body.innerHTML;

//Now iterates over the children of head to find 
//the script and style elements, and you can append them to the head of the document
var currentHead = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var scripts = head.getElementsByTagName("script");
for (var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
  currentHead.appendChild(scripts[i]);
}
//same thing for style elements, 
//you could even do that for all elements
//depending on what the response may contain
```

Comment: images should work fine. It might be that the sources are relative paths that are not valid on your page. Have you checked in the network tab if the browser attempts to download them?

Comment: No I haven't. Since it does not work in firefox and chrome on localhost and I don't know how to check for console in ie, I'll postpone this part of debug until uploading to remote server.

Comment: @user2911374 In IE you can press F12 and go to the network tab click start capturing. Then refresh your page and try the request. It will tell you what loads and what doesnt.

Comment: Thank you @stackErr . It turned out that it tries to download all css, html and javascript but not the image.

Comment: @user2911374 So do you still need help? Otherwise you should accept this answer.

Comment: @stackErr I need to load the images too. I'll accept the answer then.